# Is this not a contradiction in propositional logic (when translated)?

Tags: logic

I saw this statement, 'If you see me you won't'.

At face value I assumed this proposition was a contradiction. When translated to propositional logic, is this *not* a contradiction?

I could see it, rather, as a contingent proposition due to the difference in **won't** and **don't**:

Let $p$ = 'You see me'

Hence, $\neg p$ can be translated to, 'You *do not* see me' in English.

$\neg p$ thus holds a different truth value to the claim, 'You *will not* see me'.

Hence, the compound proposition, 'If you see me you won't', cannot be translated as:

$p$ $\implies$ $\neg p$, $\space$ can it?

But rather, something like $p \implies \neg q$, such that $q$ = 'You will see me'.

Here, the proposition is contingent.

Basic it might be, but I still want the confirmation.

Comment: Propositional logic isn't strong enough to model every thing. In fact, you can't model that much in it. I would be weary of trying to model this statement in propositional calculus. Propositional logic is more suitable to model simple statements in the present tense, or at least when every of its atoms is in the same tense, So when you ask if it is a contradiction, in propositional calculus, it doesn't make sense, it's not a meaningful statement. See [temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic).

Comment: *Hence, the compound proposition, 'If you see me you won't', cannot be translated as:* $p\implies\neg p$, *can it?* Given what I said above, I agree. The statement "You will not see me" isn't adequately captured by "you do not see me".

Comment: Thank you. What doesn't make sense, weighing if something is a contradiction based on its translation in propositional calculus?

Comment: What I claim it does not make sense is the statement  "If you see me you won't" in propositional calculus, in other words, I claim that you can't model this English statement in propositional calculus. **Edit:** It's hard for me to commit to this, though. I find your view of letting $q$ mean "You will not see me" not unacceptable. But then, of course, there is no contradiction whatsoever. If nothing comes out of this question, I suggest you ask over at [Philosophy S.E.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Apart from your concern with the difference in tense (seeing now verses not seeing later), let me just say that $p\to\neg p$ is not a contradiction. Rather, this assertion is simply equivalent to $\neg p$. That is, for me to say:  "if you'll see me, then you won't" is another way of me saying "you won't see me."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from your concern with the difference in tense (seeing now verses not seeing later, and I agree with your distinction concerning that), let me just respond to the title question. No, the propositional assertion $$p\to\neg p$$ is not a contradiction. Rather, this assertion is logically equivalent to $\neg p$, which you can see by computing the truth table. For me to say: "if you'll see me, then you won't" is another way of me saying "you won't see me."

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a contradiction: $p \rightarrow \neg p$ is equivalent to $\neg p$:

$p \rightarrow \neg p \overset{Implication}{\Leftrightarrow} \neg p \lor \neg p \overset{Idempotence}{\Leftrightarrow} \neg p$